# What is the correct way to import Vuetify components individually?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-cli

I'm new to Vuetify and it's really hard to me to know how to import only component for using it.

I am using Vuetify 2.4.2

As the documentation they said, but where is path to vuetify export?

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify' // path to vuetify export

new Vue({
  vuetify,
}).$mount('#app')
```

I use Tabs and elements like this. How can I call component from Vuetify for this?

```
 <v-card>
    <v-tabs show-arrows v-model="tab">
      <v-tabs-slider color="teal"></v-tabs-slider>
      <template v-for="sticker in allStickers">
        <v-tab :key=sticker.id :href="'#tab-'+sticker.id">
          <img :src=sticker.imgurl alt="">
        </v-tab>
      </template>
    </v-tabs>
    <v-tabs-items v-model="tab">
      <template v-for="sticker in allStickers">
        <v-tab-item :key=sticker.id :value="'tab-' + sticker.id">              
          <ul class="liststickers">
            <template v-for="stick in sticker.stickers">
              <li :key=stick.id @click="sendSelectedSticker(stick.id)">
                <img :src=stick.imgurl alt="">
                <p class="stick_price">{{stick.price}}</p>
              </li>
            </template>
          </ul>
        </v-tab-item>
      </template>
    </v-tabs-items>
  </v-card>
```

Thank you for your support

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Vue CLI + Vuetify

If you are using Vue CLI and `vue add vuetify`, then this functionality is already handled by the vuetify-loader and there is nothing you need to do.  From the Vuetify [Treeshaking docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/#treeshaking):

> The A la carte system enables you to pick and choose which components to import, drastically lowering your build size. *New projects created with the Vue CLI plugin have this enabled **by default***.

## Manual Installation

For a manual installation of Vuetify, choose whether you want to register the components globally or on a per-component basis.  Both options will load only the Vuetify components you need, but global registration lets you avoid having to write the `import` syntax inside each of your components. Following is an example using `<v-tabs>` in each setup.

#### Global registration

Use this if you don't want to have to manually import the selected Vuetify components into each of your components that uses them.

*main.js*

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Vuetify, {
  VApp,
  VTabs,
  VTab
} from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  components: {
    VApp,
    VTabs,
    VTab
  },
})
const vuetify = new Vuetify({});

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Now you can use the `<v-app>`, `<v-tabs>`, and `<v-tab>` in any component.

---

#### Per-component registration

Use this if you *do* want to manually register Vuetify components in each of your components which uses them.

*main.js*

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)
const vuetify = new Vuetify({});

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

App.vue

```js
import { VApp, VTabs, VTab } from 'vuetify/lib'

export default {
  components: {
    VApp,
    VTabs,
    VTab
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer has helped me setting up Vuetify3 beta